# Asserting values contained within Javascript Arrays using Mocha and Chai

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

What is a good/optimal way of asserting for values contained within an array, imported into a Test Suite, given the following code (which does not work obviously :)

```js
it('Grant all email phone perms', async() => {
  const vals = await doSomeStuff(page, frame);

  expect(vals[0]).to.equal('option| 1');
  expect(vals[1]).to.equal('option| 2');
  expect(vals[2]).to.equal('option| 3');
  expect(vals[3]).to.equal('option| 4');

});
```

Where, at runtime, I can see `vals` contains:

```
vals: Object{val1: "option|1", val2: "option|2", val3: "option|3", val4: "option|4"}
```

I'm sure this is basic stuff, but I am just learning!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know exactly what the result should look like you can use deep equal.

```
expect(vals).to.deep.equal({val1: "option|1", val2: "option|2", val3: "option|3", val4: "option|4"})
```

Also it looks like your data is an object not an array. But deep equal works great for arrays too

Comment: On side note : Array is also an object in JS. type this in your console `console.log(typeof [])` and see.

Answer (score 0):

As alternative, we can also use `eql` which is shorter than `deep.equal`

```
expect(vals).to.eql({val1: "option|1", val2: "option|2", val3: "option|3", val4: "option|4"})
```

Reference:
https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_eql

Answer (score 0):

I'm still looking for a way to do partials (deepEqual doesn't work for me). But your object is an object, not an array.  The least amount of changes to your original code would be as follows

```js
  expect(vals.val1).to.equal('option| 1');
  expect(vals.val2).to.equal('option| 2');
  expect(vals.val3).to.equal('option| 3');
  expect(vals.val4).to.equal('option| 4');
```